MySQL - как выбрать записи в одной таблице , в которых значение "количество" больше чем сумма "количество" в другой таблице
Есть две таблицы MySQL с разной структурой связанные между собой некоторыми полями.
В первой таблице есть поле "count" с которого берётся количество для другой таблицы и разбивается на части , и заносится в поле "count" в другую таблицу.
Требуется выбрать из первой таблицы все значения в которых значение "count" ,больше чем сумма поля "count" в другой таблице.

Требуется получить "part_id" которого №2

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

больше чем сумма поля "count" в другой таблице Ну вот совершенно очевидно, что первым делом надо получить эту самую "сумму поля count в другой таблице". Тогда можно будет сравнивать.

Изначально использовал такой запрос SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE part_id = table1.part_id  AND code = table2.code)
Но обнаружилось что есть "хвосты" по количеству и их нужно выявлять.

SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT part_id, SUM(`count`) sum_count
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY 1
    ) t3 ON t1.part_id = t3.part_id AND t1.`count` <= t3.sum_count
WHERE t3.part_id IS NULL

Суть. Агрегируем и суммируем вторую таблицу. Затем результат связываем с первой по равенству part_id и условию, что сумма в первой - НЕ больше. Если это условие не выполняется, или если во второй таблице нет нужного part_id (типа сумма равна нулю, но на самом деле NULL), то на месте полей второй таблицы будет NULL. А именно такие записи нам и нужны.
fiddle

@像插頭一樣愚蠢 по условиям задачи нигде не сказано, что нужно учесть вероятность того, что в таблицах могут присутствовать не связанные между собой записи. Такую возможность следует учитывать абсолютно всегда. MySQL в принципе не умеет вставлять в более чем одну таблицу одновременно - а потому такая ситуация гарантированно бывает. вас мама в детстве не учила, что брать чужой код и выдавать его за свой - нехорошо? Это какой же у меня код - чужой? тыкните пальцем, что ли...

@像插頭一樣愚蠢 Давайте следовать условиям задачи Приглядитесь к комментарию автора с итоговым запросом под вашим ответом... особенно к добавленному им .. OR NOT EXISTS ... Автор ещё не очень опытен в формулировании задач. Можно, конечно, дать ему то, что он спросил, но лучше - сразу дать то, что он хотел, и с соответствующими пояснениями.
